# The result is not shown on webpage or it shows very slowly

Tags: javascript, html, json

So... the code is like this

```
<script>
console.log("Calculating the number of cases...");

calculate_total();

function calculate_total() {
fetch('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json')
.then(res => {
return res.json()
})
.then (raw_data => {
var total_cases = 0;
var new_cases = 0;
var total_deaths = 0;

for (const key in raw_data) {
const country = raw_data[key];
const country_data = country.data;
const latest_data = country_data[country_data.length - 1];
if (country.location != "World") {
if (latest_data.total_cases != null) {
total_cases += latest_data.total_cases;
}
if (latest_data.new_cases != null) {
new_cases += latest_data.new_cases;
}
if (latest_data.total_deaths != null) {
total_deaths += latest_data.total_deaths;
}
}
}
console.log("Number of total cases:" + total_cases);
console.log("Number of new confirmed cases:" + new_cases);
console.log("Number of deaths:" + total_deaths);

document.getElementById("total_cases").innerHTML = total_cases;
document.getElementById("new_cases").innerHTML = new_cases;
document.getElementById("total_deaths").innerHTML = total_deaths;
})
}


</script>
```

The result actually show what I want to see, however it probably takes 5 minutes until the result shows.
What should I change in order to get the result instantly or less waiting time?

Comment: I think that it's because your wifi connection is weak though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is around 35mb and the complete traversal of the JSON using the for loop is expected to take a long time. 
Also, trying to convert this long stringified version of the JSON also takes compute time.

You cannot do much but try to get only the fields that you require (*this is possible if fetching data from a GraphQL API*). This way the result you get only contains the fields that you want to work with which I guess in this case will significantly reduce the compute time